# What is this bash built-in's printf's %a format specifier?

Tags: bash, printf, undocumented-behavior

Using Bash 5.0.17(1)-release

Performing:

```sh
LC_NUMERIC=C printf '%a\n' 0.0
```

Outputs:

```
0x0p+0
```

Testing multiple values:

```sh
for v in 1.0 2.0 42.0 3.141592653589793
  do LC_NUMERIC=C printf '%-20s %a\n' "$v" "$v"
done
```

Output is:

```
1.0                  0x8p-3
2.0                  0x8p-2
42.0                 0xa.8p+2
3.141592653589793    0xc.90fdaa22168bde9p-2
```

What is this `%a` format specifier, I could not find documented with `man bash` or `help printf` or searching the web?

Comment: https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/builtins/printf.def#L661 Also https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/d233b485e83c3a784b803fb894280773f16f2deb/lib/sh/snprintf.c#L1316

Comment: I could find the documentation of this format within `man printf.3` which displays the c language documentation for `printf`. `C99;  not in SUSv2, but added in SUSv3) For a conversion, the double argument is converted to hexadecimal notation...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is this `%a` format specifier, I could not find documented with `man bash` or `help printf` or searching the web?

It provides the same function as the same format specifier used with the C standard library's [`printf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) function.  Specifically, it prints a hexadecimal representation of a floating-point number.